# Call function in XPath expression

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have a custom XSLT function that tests a node for a type (which involves string matching, thus it is in its own function), but I am not sure how to correctly use this in an XPath expression. The my:isType() function should test the nodes which are returned by the `//cell` xpath expression and not the outer node from `xsl:when`.

```
<xsl:when test="...">
    <my:elem>
        <xsl:value-of select="//cell[@parent = @id and my:istype(., 'type')]/@id"/>
    </my:elem>
</xsl:when>
```

Also am I correct, that the @id in `//cell[@parent = @id]` refers to the outer node?

Edit: include function definition:

```
<xsl:function name="my:istype" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="contains($element/@style, concat('type=', $type, ';'))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: It would really help if you showed the function declaration of your `my:istype` function. The `.` inside of the predicate certainly would pass each selected `cell` element as the first argument to the `my:istype` function.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I updated the question with the function definition.

Comment: Inside the predicate attached to `//cell` (i.e. the expression in square brackets) all three subexpressions, namely `@parent`, `@id` and `.` are evaluated with the `cell` element as the context node. So you compare both the `parent` and the `id` attribute of the `cell` and you pass the `cell` to your function. As for an `xsl:when`, it doesn't not even change the current node, mainly `for-each`, `apply-templates`, `iterate` do that

Comment: This means I have to use `//cell[@parent = current()/@id and my:istype(., 'type')]/@id` if I want to match against the ID of the outer node?

Comment: Yes, `current()/@id` will select the `id` attribute of the "outer" node, i.e. the node processed currently in the context of a `for-each` or `apply-templates` or `iterate` or `for-each-group`. In general it is (in XSLT 2 and 3) a context item, part of the "focus": https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#focus.

Comment: You forgot to provide a small source XML document against which to run the transformation. Please, do. Also, providing just a fragment of a template isn't helpful -- are you expecting the wild guess of the solvers to be correct? What is the current() node? To what node is the current template being applied? This is the XPath and XSLT tags, not the Riddles tag

Comment: Kleinph, you are asking: "Also am I correct, that the @id in //cell[@parent = @id] refers to the outer node?" What do you mean by "outer node"?in this expression both attributes are the attributes of the context item (`cell`)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev with outer node I meant the node selected by the `<when>` tag. As @Martin Honnen already pointed out it's not the case as I thougt. I am sorry that I provided not enough information for you. but the issue is solved for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments one has to use `current()` to refer to the context node and a `.` is used to refer to the current cell node in the XPath expression.

```
<xsl:when test="...">
    <my:elem>
        <xsl:value-of select="//cell[@parent = current()/@id and my:istype(., 'type')]/@id"/>
    </my:elem>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: kleinph, the `<xsl:when>` element doesn't "match" any node. Its `select` attribute contains an XPath expression that is evaluated as a boolean.. Please, correct the misleading statement in this answer.

Comment: Of course. Would "... the selected node of the `<xsl:when>` element ..." be more correct, or should I drop the fragment in the parenthesis completely?

Comment: kleinph -- There is nothing that is "the selected node of the `<xsl:when>`". You may try to say: "the `current()` node